# update packages on red hat without internet connection

Tags: r, redhat, cran, lzma, xz

I am using Red Hat 6.4 without internet connection. I am trying to install R using CRAN. While I install some dependencies are needed. Some of them are already installed on the server. The issue is when I installed the one of dependency. For example, I need xz version 5.0.3. The server already have xz version 4.9. Is there anyway to update the version of xz? I already tried to install over 4.9 using tar.gz file, but it did not work.

Comment: can you be more specific about "did not work"?  Have you checked `.libPaths()` (i.e., maybe you installed to a different library and the old version is masking the new version). `?remove.packages` ?

Comment: you could remove xz and install the version that you need once you have the source on disk, I think it still uses yum so just do "yum remove xz-a.b.c" and then "rpm -Uvh foo.rpm", then continue doing the installation